# Account Limit Reached

Tags: icloud

I've got two computers - both using Mac Mojave and I got this error when I try to login to my apple account.

On first computer, I created apple ID, and tried to login on the second computer.

[image]

Comment: How many devices do you see listed in either iCloud preferences online/ or in the sys pref app ?

Comment: Only one - my second computer.